# Laravel save() not working on new object

Tags: laravel, authorization, entrust

I'm trying to use the code provided by the documentation of entrust in a controller but `save()` method wont execute and gives me the error

> Method [save] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\role]

Here is the code:

```
$cityadmin = new Role();
$cityadmin->name= 'cityadmin';
$cityadmin->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full namespace:

```
$cityadmin = new \App\Role;
```

Or add this to the top of the controller:

```
use App\Role;
```